# Ho to disable TLS 1.3 in Vertx, it is creating issue while connecting with MmongoDB client

Tags: java, vert.x, mongodb-java, openjdk-11, tls1.3

I am developing an application on Vertx Java and using Mongodb as database,
when i am trying to connect Mongodb instance it is throwing below error

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:311)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLExtensions.<init>(SSLExtensions.java:90)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateRequest$T13CertificateRequestMessage.<init>(CertificateRequest.java:818)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateRequest$T13CertificateRequestConsumer.consume(CertificateRequest.java:922)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1260)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1247)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:770)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1192)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.impl.TlsChannelImpl.handleTask(TlsChannelImpl.java:271)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.impl.TlsChannelImpl.handshakeLoop(TlsChannelImpl.java:599)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.impl.TlsChannelImpl.handshake(TlsChannelImpl.java:554)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.impl.TlsChannelImpl.doHandshake(TlsChannelImpl.java:529)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.impl.TlsChannelImpl.handshake(TlsChannelImpl.java:511)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.impl.TlsChannelImpl.write(TlsChannelImpl.java:385)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.ClientTlsChannel.write(ClientTlsChannel.java:181)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.async.AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.writeHandlingTasks(AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.java:553)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.async.AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.doWrite(AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.java:501)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.async.AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.access$400(AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.java:67)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.async.AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup$6.run(AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.java:459)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
... 1 more
```

> The following exception may occur when using OCSP stapling with Java
> runtime environments that use the TLS 1.3 protocol (Java 11 and higher
> use TLS 1.3 by default):
>
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be
> presented in certificate_request
>
> The exception is due to a known issue with TLS 1.3 in Java 11 and
> higher. To avoid this exception when using a Java runtime environments
> using the TLS 1.3 protocol, you can force the application to use the
> TLS 1.2 protocol. To do this, set the jdk.tls.client.protocols system
> property to “TLSv1.2”.

So i tried passing VM argument
[image]

But No luck, Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following system property.

`-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2`

Just for your reference this is the issue raised in the OpenJdk bug tracker
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8236039

it is marked as fixed in version 15.

Comment: I have already added system property in environment variables still it's not picking up

Comment: Try with TLSv1.2, are you getting the same error? Enable -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake and check 1) if the system property is picked up and 2) what's happening on TLS handshake.

Comment: If you can upgrade your JDK version to 15 it should work too.